# Rake db:reset has not updated change from integer to bigint; Sqlite supports bigint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I have a hypothesis on what's going on... want to ask the community.

My latest migration is to change phone number from `integer` to `bigint` per the requirements of PG on Heroku. My schema file, which is updated to reflect the latest migration (as in the dates match), still shows:

```
t.integer "phone"
```

Therefore when I run a `rake db:reset`, the phone is still an `integer`, which is a problem for PG in Heroku because then I get errors since `integer` doesn't support the values I need it to.

Is this possibly just a reflection of the fact that my development database which is sqlite uses `integer` as `bigint` per this file? http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3

I ask this just to make sure that the rest of the database is aligned... I'm not a bit paranoid that a bunch of other migrations have been missed somehow.

The other thing is, if my hypothesis IS correct, then how can I force bigint as a definition in the schema to avoid things like this happening in the future? Is the only way to make the local database also PG?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that would be better to store a phone as a string not as a bigint

Comment: You really should be using the same database in dev, test, and production anyway. Don't expect ActiveRecord to offer much in the way of useful portability.

Answer (score 0):

From http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

> Each value stored in an SQLite database (or manipulated by the database engine) has one of the following storage classes:
>
> - INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

So assuming your bindings use `sqlite3_bind_int64` where appropriate, SQLite supports 64-bit integers seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** Phone numbers are text, not numbers. Rails understands SQLite better than you do. If you want consistent behavior, use PostgreSQL in development, test, and production.

First, SQL bigint is the wrong data type for phone numbers. Phone numbers can have leading zeroes, but numbers (including bigints) can't.

Second, SQLite doesn't even *have* data types in the SQL sense.

```
sqlite>     create table test (
   ...>       test_id integer
   ...>     );
sqlite>     
sqlite>     insert into test values ('wibble');
sqlite>     select * from test;
test_id   
----------
wibble
```

Third, you can use *any* token as a data type in SQLite. Anything at all. Want a "data type" called "kate_mara"?

```
sqlite> drop table test;
sqlite> create table test (
   ...>   n kate_mara
   ...> );
sqlite> insert into test values (42);
sqlite> select * from test;
n                   
--------------------
42                  
sqlite> .dump test
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE test (
  n kate_mara
);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(42);
COMMIT;
```

Fourth, SQLite's integer storage class can store 64-bit values. (So can kate_mara, for that matter.)

```
sqlite> drop table test;
sqlite> create table test (
   ...>   n integer
   ...> );
sqlite> insert into test values (0);
sqlite> insert into test values (2147483647); -- Biggest 32-bit int
sqlite> insert into test values (9223372036854775807); -- Biggest 64-bit int
sqlite> .width 20
sqlite> select * from test;
n                   
--------------------
0                   
2147483647          
9223372036854775807
```

That's the upper bound for SQLite integers. Any higher, and it switches to a floating-point number without error or warning.

```
sqlite> update test set n = n + 1;
sqlite> select * from test;
n                   
--------------------
1                   
2147483648          
9.22337203685478e+18
```